# LCD Projector Aspect Ratio Wrong for my 1.3 aspect iamges

Tags: aspect-ratio

I acquired an Epson LCD PowerLite 53C Multimedia Projector at Thrift Shop. This LCD projector is immaculate, like it has never been used.

This model projector expects a VGA input via a DE-15 pin connector. Other options are S-Video or composite video. My laptop only provides HDMI. I connect it via an HDMI to VGA adapter.

This lash-up correctly projects an image of my computer screen and the wallpaper image.  Also, when I project MP4 movies, they project correct as to their aspect ratio.

I have lots of travel shots made using my Panasonic DMC-ZS40. I use this camera a lot for casual snapshots while traveling as it has a GPS feature.

My problem: All my Panasonic images are 4896 X 3672 = 1.33 aspect ratio. These show correctly when imputed to several of my TV sets. However, when projected via the 53C they come out distorted, too tall too skinny.

The 53C manual doesn’t address this problem. Also, the 53C doesn’t seem to have an obvious way to make an aspect ratio adjustment.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a problem of OS, image display application and PC display hardware.

Comment: How to properly display a photo is definitely on topic...

Comment: I think this question is better suited to [su] than to Photo-SE.